# How to send a file in a url via curl?

Tags: http, curl, https, http-headers, ipfs

I have an image in a URL like https://i.postimg.cc/GpDskmSG/sdssds.png and I want to send it over to be stored at nft.storage. Could I send it directly as a URL instead of a file from a path? I tried the below but it only stores the image URL.

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIwetertyrtyUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6Ikp" -H "Content-Type: image/png" --data "https://i.postimg.cc/GpDskmSG/sdssds.png" --url "https://api.nft.storage/upload"
```

P/S: I'm testing on windows curl.

Answer (score 0):

According to the API docs (https://nft.storage/api-docs/), it will accept multipart/form-data for this type of POST.

You can try using -F/--form instead, for which a good example exists on the curl man page (https://linux.die.net/man/1/curl):

```
curl -F "web=@index.html;type=text/html" url.com
```